# RxJava: split a list inside of an object, do some operation, and then combine the modified list back into the original container object

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a RetroFit service call that returns the response as an `Observable`. In the response, there is a list of items in which I am using `flatMap` to make additional service calls to add some data to the response.  I was the final returned `Observable` be one that emits the original message with the updated list.  After the `zip` operator, I am left with an `Observable<BrowseResult>` but I need to combined that the original response so that I have an `Observable<BrowseRespose>`.  I looked into `collect` and `concat` operators but could not figure out how to apply it to my problem.  Any recommendations on what operators to utilize?

```
protected Observable<BrowseResponse> buildUseCaseObservable() {
    BrowseQuery.Builder builder = new BrowseQuery.Builder()
            .start(mStartIndex);

    return mBrowseApi.getMultimedia(builder.build())
            .flatMap(response -> Observable.from(
                    response.getResultsWrapper().getResult()))
            .flatMap(result -> {
                Observable<MultimediaObject> imageObjectObservable =
                        mMultimediaApi.getImageByEntitlement(result.getEid(), true);
                Observable<BrowseResult> browseResultObservable = Observable.just(result);
                return Observable.zip(browseResultObservable, imageObjectObservable,
                        (browseResult, imageObject) -> {
                            result.setImageUrl(imageObject.getAuthenticatedStoreUrl());
                            return result;
                        }
                );
            });
}
```

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: @akarnokd I updated to state my question more clearly.

Comment: You can use `toList()` to obtain a `List<BrowseResult>`. I suppose that having the `List`, you can now create/edit and return a `BrowseResponse`. The second `flatMap` is a bit messy. I would put more thought into it.